# VB6 Disable system beep sound when arrow up/down is pressed inside rich text box?

Tags: vb6, richtextbox, keypress, beep, system-sounds

I have a Rich Text Box control. It has no scroll bars, cause I am using Mouse Wheel module to capture Mouse Wheel events.

When the rich text box is selected and mouse wheel is rotated up/down it sends keys {UP} and {DOWN} to they rich text box to "mimic" the scroll effect.

However, when you are at the beginning or at the ending of the text box content (e.g there's nothing to scroll anymore), there's annoying beep system sound playing. I need to disable this, any ideas how to do that ?

Already tried adding this code in the rich text box's keypress event:

```
If KeyAscii = 38 Or KeyAscii = 40 Then
KeyAscii = 0
End If
```

Doesn't work. Don't know why it just doesn't work when it is supposed to be working.

Comment: Can you add more of your code?

Comment: PLEASE be more careful when tagging your question. VB6 is NOT VBA!!! Tagging properly is also to your benefit since then the right people will see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `KeyDown` event instead of `KeyPress`, and disable the `KeyCode` only if the cursor is located at the first/last line to prevent disabling the arrow keys (up/down) completely.

First you need to add the following to the declarations:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long
Private Const EM_LINEFROMCHAR = &HC9
Private Const EM_GETLINECOUNT = &HBA

Private Function GetCurrentLine(Txt As RichTextBox) As Long
    GetCurrentLine = SendMessage(Txt.hWnd, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, Txt.SelStart, 0&) + 1
End Function

Private Function GetLineCount(Txt As RichTextBox) As Long
    GetLineCount = SendMessage(Txt.hWnd, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0&, 0&)
End Function
```

Then use the `KeyDown` event as described:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then
        If GetCurrentLine(RichTextBox1) = 1 Then KeyCode = 0
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
        If GetCurrentLine(RichTextBox1) = GetLineCount(RichTextBox1) Then KeyCode = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course you'll need to replace `RichTextBox1` with the name of your RichTextBox.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: When i do that, i am not able to scroll in the text box with the mousewheel anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I've edited my answer, it will do exactly what you want.. please check it

Comment: This has actually worked pretty well! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a function/sub

```
Public Declare Function SendMessageByVal Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

In your sub/function

```
Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETEDITSTYLE, SES_ALLOWBEEPS + SES_USECRLF, SES_ALLOWBEEPS + SES_USECRLF)
```

To see more see http://ambracode.com/index/show/1405175 which is some copy of an old post I made at SO.

Comment: What a childish comment. That shows a technique. You actually have to write code.

Comment: What should i say more ? It just doesn't work. I added it exactly how you describe it.

Comment: It code lifted from a program. You need to do a lot more. You will have to read the docs for RTF WINDOWS, get the constants, read up on EDIT CONTROL styles and SendMessage. The link shows it in context. But you still need to get constants from winuser.h in Windows Software Development Kit. This used to be at MSDN http://www.helpdoc-online.com/SCDMS01EN1A195P593~MSDN-Library-2001-Periodicals-1999-en~Extend-Control-Functionality-With-API-Calls.htm and http://www.helpdoc-online.com/SCDMS01EN1A195P617~MSDN-Library-2001-Periodicals-1999-en~Uncover-Secret-Control-Properties.htm